# Javascript syntax - change text color onscroll

Tags: javascript, text, syntax, colors, navigation

i am using this javascript code to change the background color of the nav to match the color of the site background as the user scrolls.

I want the text of the nav to change to white but im not sure of the syntax, i was thinking to put

```
lis[i].style.color ="white";
```

but its not working - http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/287/

```
window.onscroll = function () {
var offset = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop),
    lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

var colorMap = [
    { value: 250, color : '#e01246'} ,
    { value: 800, color : '#1d1d1d' },
    { value: 2800, color: 'purple'}
];

console.log(offset);
    var isColorSet = false;
     for (var i=0; i<colorMap.length; i++) {
         lis[i].style.background='white';
         if (!isColorSet && offset < colorMap[i].value) {
             lis[i].style.background = colorMap[i].color;
             isColorSet = true;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: see here it is working http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/290/.I applied yellow colour

Comment: no, i mean the color of the text, i want the text to turn white at the same time as the background changes